# A number box (jump from 0 to 9) in the view in iPhone . How should I do?

Tags: iphone, numbers

I mean I have a `UIImageView`, and I want to put a number on it. And then the number jumps from 0 to 9.

Comment: do u mean a label or textfield with changing text(number)?

Comment: what do u mean by changing number,Explain briefly, then only we can help you out.

Answer (score 3):

I guess (you should definitely explain in more detail what you want to do) you want to display a number that is changing over time.

Suppose you have an UILabel which displays the number:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
  UILabel *myNumberLabel;
}
@end

@implementation MyViewController
  - (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
      myNumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)]; //or some other rect..
      [self.view addSubView:myNumberLabel];
    }
    return self;
  }

  - (void)dealloc {
    [myNumberLabel release];
    [super dealloc];
  }

  - (void)updateNumber:(NSNumber*)number {
    [myNumberLabel setText:[number stringValue]];
  }
@end
```